# Pin properties in Diptrace

Tags: diptrace

Looking for definitions of items under `Type` and `Electric` in Diptrace Component Editor. I know it's for `ERC` control, but official tutorial doesn't cover this properly.

[image]
[image]

What is the difference between `Type` and `Electric`? If anyone could describe any item, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not used diptrace, I'll try to answer this question. I believe that the **type** adds a aesthetic characteristic to the symbol. For example adding a circle/bubble for inverted outputs or inputs, adding a > symbol to clock, etc. This is for display and readability purposes only.

On the other hand the **electric** parameter is used in the actual ERC. For example if the pin is defined as an input in the symbol, if it not connected in the schematic, flag has to be raised in ERC.

*Further Reading*: [Inside OrCAD Capture for Windows By Chris Schroeder](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=0750670630)

Comment: Thanks. However, could you recommend some place where I can read about schematics notations for `Type`? Can you update your answer and tell what might be difference between Passive and Bidirectional? Open/Passive High/Low? Which combination can I use for GND/Power supply?

Comment: @Pablo **Bidrectional** pins can act as input or output depending on the internal state of the device. **Passive** pins are generally found on passive devices like resistors or discrete semiconductors without external power connections. Hope this clarifies.